# trying to map data inside of already mapped data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui, mapping

data set 1 is an array, that contains another array data set 2. Data set 1 is currently mapped over to display a single column table with data1.name inside of it. data1.name is a button that can be clicked to display related data2.data. The current problem I am facing is that data sets that are unrelated to their respective parents are displaying in all the parent data locations. For instance, clicking data1[a] will display all the data2.data from data1[b] and so on and so forth. When i input a new data1, with new data2 nested. The data that is previously rendered in all the data1 sets is replaced by this new data.

I've attached my code in hopes that someone may be able to shed some light. Please beware that I am using an MUI library so the code is a bit bulky. There is a table, that maps over data1 to display each data1.name and then data.2 is mapped relatively immediately after presenting the user with a modal display of the data1.data2.data.

```
    const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
}));

const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
  '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
  },
  // hide last border
  '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': {
    border: 0,
  },
}));

const Reports = () => {

 //GRAB THE USER PROFILE
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({ months: [] })
      useEffect(() => {
         axios.get('/api/users/profile', {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user')}`
          }
        }
        )
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            setUsers({...users, months: res.data.months })
            console.log(users.months)
          })
      }, [])

      // defining modal styles
  const style = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    width: 1000,
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: 24,
    p: 4,
  };

  // defining modal state
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);



  return (
    <>
      <NavBar></NavBar>
      <br></br>      <br></br>
      <h1 style={{ color: "white", textAlign: "center", fontSize: "50px" }}>Budget Summaries</h1>
      <br></br>      <br></br>

      <Container>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={0} md={1}>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={10}>
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
              <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <StyledTableCell style={{ fontSize: "25px" }}>Month</StyledTableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {users.months.map(month => (
                    <StyledTableRow key={month._id}>
                      <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        <Button onClick={handleOpen}>{month.name}</Button>
                        <Modal
                          open={open}
                          onClose={handleClose}
                          aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
                          aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
                        >
                          <Box sx={style}>
                            <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
                              <Container>
                                < Grid container spacing={2} >
                                  <Grid item xs={0} md={1}>
                                  </Grid>
                                  <Grid item xs={12} md={10}>
                                    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                                      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
                                        <TableHead>
                                          <TableRow>
                                            <StyledTableCell style={{ fontSize: "25px" }}>Categories</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell style={{ fontSize: "25px" }} align="right">Spent</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell style={{ fontSize: "25px" }} align="right">Goals</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell style={{ fontSize: "25px" }} align="right">Results</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell style={{ fontSize: "25px" }} align="right"></StyledTableCell>
                                          </TableRow>
                                        </TableHead>
                                        <TableBody>
                                          {month.categories.map(category => (
                                            <StyledTableRow key={category.name}>
                                              <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                                {category.name}
                                              </StyledTableCell>
                                              <StyledTableCell align="right">{category.actualValue}</StyledTableCell>
                                              <StyledTableCell align="right">{category.goalValue}</StyledTableCell>
                                              <StyledTableCell align="right">{category.result}</StyledTableCell>
                                              <StyledTableCell align="right"></StyledTableCell>
                                            </StyledTableRow>
                                          ))}
                                        </TableBody>
                                      </Table>
                                    </TableContainer>
                                  </Grid>
                                  <Grid item xs={0} md={1}>
                                  </Grid>
                                </Grid >
                              </Container >
                            </Typography>
                          </Box>
                        </Modal>
                      </StyledTableCell>
                    </StyledTableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={0} md={1}>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
      <br></br><br></br>
      <hr style={{ color: "white" }}></hr>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </>
  )
}

export default Reports
```

Comment: Consider replacing `const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);` with an object like so: `const [open, setOpen] = useState({});`. Then, pass down any unique identifier for the month (let's say `monthId`) into both `handleOpen` and `handleClose`. So, those two methods become like so: `const handleOpen = monthId => setOpen(prev => ({...prev, [monthId]: true}));` and `const handleClose = monthId => setOpen(prev => ({...prev, [monthId]: false}));` Plus, Modal open becomes `<Modal open={open[monthId]} ...>`. This will ensure only specific month's modal will open & close; and not all modals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try replacing below code snippets as suggested:

1.

```
// defining modal state
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
```

with

```
// defining modal state
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState({});
const handleOpen = monthId => setOpen(prev => ({...prev, [monthId]: true}));
const handleClose = monthId => setOpen(prev => ({...prev, [monthId]: false}));
```

2. 

```
<Button onClick={handleOpen}>{month.name}</Button>
<Modal
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
  aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
  aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
>
```

with

```
<Button onClick={() => handleOpen(month._id)}>{month.name}</Button>
<Modal
  open={open[month._id]}
  onClose={() => handleClose(month._id)}
  aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
  aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
>
```

**Explanation**

- The current code has only one state-variable named `open` which gets set to `true` any time user clicks on the `month.name` button.
- When it is set to true, all of the modals which have `<Modal open={open}...` will be rendered/displayed
- The changes suggested above will make `open` an object of the form `{ monthId1: false, monthId2: true, ......}`
- Changes to `handleOpen` and `handleClose` will ensure only a particular month's open/close flag is updated
- Replacing `<Modal open={open} ....` with `<Modal open={open[month._id]} ....`, ensures that each modal uses the true/false specific to the `month._id`.
- NOTE: If `month._id` may be duplicated, then use a different unique attribute. If no such attribute exists, then replace `{users.months.map(month => (` with `{users.months.map((month, monthIndex) => (` and use `monthIndex`.

**Observation / Note**

We may avoid `handleOpen`, `handleClose` methods by using a simple `flip` method like so:

```
const flip = monthId => setOpen(prev => ({...prev, [monthId]: !prev[monthId]}));
```

So, both `onClick` and `onClose` will become something like so:

```
{() => flip(month._id)}
```

Comment: Wow this is an incredibly thorough response. I thank you for taking the time to explain what was happening versus what needs to happen. This has fixed my issue and I can now move further with this project. Thank you!!